# Comparing register values in x64 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to figure out a puzzle based on the existing values in the assembly registries.

I keep running into trouble at this line

```
cmp    %sil,0x12(%rdi)
jne    ...
```

The 12th offset for `%rdi` and `%sil` do in fact contain the same values when I examine them in the debugger, but the program still jumps because the values are considered not equal.

The only thing I can think of is that the previous comparisons were using `cmpb` instead of `cmp` and that `%sil` being the 1-byte version for `%rsi`is being compared against an 8-byte value.

Can someone tell me if I'm thinking about this correctly? If so, the input for the solution is a string so how would I change the input to accommodate for this?

Comment: `0x12` (hex) is not 12 (decimal).  It's the 18th byte after `(%rdi)`.  This `cmp` is a `cmpb`, the byte operand-size is implied by the register operand so the disassembler omitted it.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhh, I see. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
0x12(%rdi)
```

Is the hex representation for a decimal not the offset itself